# Fading in text in Android using AnimationUtils.loadAnimation

Tags: android, android-animation

I would be very grateful if someone could explain to me why this works:

```
private void startAnimating() {
    TextView logo1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.Shizzle);   
        final Animation fade1 = new AlphaAnimation(0.0f, 1.0f);  
        fade1.setDuration(3000);
        logo1.startAnimation(fade1);
        }
```

But this doesn't work at all for me:

```
private void startAnimating() {
    TextView logo1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.Shizzle);   
        Animation fade1 = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this,R.anim.fade_in);  
    logo1.startAnimation(fade1);    
    }
```

The fade_in.xml associated with the above is:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/android"
    android:shareInterpolator="false">
    <alpha
        android:fromAlpha="0.0"
        android:toAlpha="1.0"
        android:duration="3000">
    </alpha>
```

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Works for me:
Create two file in folder **/res/anim** - **fadein.xml**, **fadeout.xml**

fadein:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shareInterpolator="false" >

    <alpha
        android:duration="500"
        android:fromAlpha="0.0"
        android:toAlpha="1.0" >
    </alpha>

</set>
```

fadeout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shareInterpolator="false" >

    <alpha
        android:duration="200"
        android:fromAlpha="1.0"
        android:toAlpha="0.0" >
    </alpha>

</set>
```

initialize code:

```
Animation animFadeIn, animFadeOut;
...
animFadeIn=AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.fadein);
animFadeOut=AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.fadeout);
```

...
using:

```
case R.id.imgBtnShowContent:
    rlOrderBtns.startAnimation(animFadeIn);
    rlOrderBtns.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
break;

case R.id.imgBtnHideContent:
    rlOrderBtns.startAnimation(animFadeOut);
    rlOrderBtns.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
break;
```