# Animate layout's background color change

Tags: android, android-layout, animation, android-animation, android-view

I have a `RelativeLayout` to which I have set a background from `drawable`.I was able to change the background of `RelativeLayout` to another when the `RadioButton` is checked. But how do I give an animation to it when it changes?

Code:
activity_main.xml:

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="80dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:background="@drawable/original"
    android:id="@+id/rel1">
    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/radio"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

original.xml(drawable):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">
    <solid
        android:color="#ffffff">
    </solid>
    <corners
        android:radius="50dp">
    </corners>
</shape>
```

pressed.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">
    <solid
        android:color="#2196F3">
    </solid>
    <corners
        android:radius="50dp">
    </corners>
</shape>
```

Java Class:

```
radio.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton compoundButton, boolean b) {
                    if(b){
                    relativeLayout.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.pressed);
                }
            }
        });
```

Comment: you can do it using `ObjectAnimator` easily

Comment: Could you provide me with a code

Comment: try this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11419141/fading-in-text-in-android-using-animationutils-loadanimation

Comment: Please provide an answer

Comment: what type animation you want to use

Answer (score 7):

The problem boils down to having somehow clipped corners and animating the layout background. So, in theory, we can set a foreground drawable to the layout and animate background drawable using `ArgbEvaluator`.

Moving to practice.

Take a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8313096/1083957), where the author shares a mask drawable, which can be handy for your problem:

[image]

Apply that drawable as a foreground of your layout:

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="300dp"
    android:foreground="@drawable/frame"
    android:background="@color/colorAccent" />
```

In the code, whenever needed to perform animation:

```
    final int from = ContextCompat.getColor(this, R.color.colorAccent);
    final int to   = ContextCompat.getColor(this, R.color.colorPrimary);

    ValueAnimator anim = new ValueAnimator();
    anim.setIntValues(from, to);
    anim.setEvaluator(new ArgbEvaluator());
    anim.addUpdateListener(new ValueAnimator.AnimatorUpdateListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAnimationUpdate(ValueAnimator valueAnimator) {
            view.setBackgroundColor((Integer)valueAnimator.getAnimatedValue());
        }
    });

    anim.setDuration(1000);
    anim.start();
```

Here's what you'll get on output:

[image]

If you want to change frame drawable's color, you can wrap it into an `xml` and apply `android:tint`.

```
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item >
        <bitmap android:src="@drawable/frame" android:tint="#ccaaff"/>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

Now set this drawable as the foreground of your layout.

Comment: When I set drawable as foreground the radio button became invisible

Comment: When I set colorAccent as background the edges are of diiferent color

Comment: Please post a simple project with that behavior.

Answer (score 0):

**The same effect can be achieved entirely in Code**

Create Background with Corner of Rectangle Programmatically

```
    //Background
    backgroundDrawable = GradientDrawable()
    backgroundDrawable.cornerRadius = rectangleCornerRadius
    backgroundDrawable.shape = GradientDrawable.RECTANGLE
    backgroundDrawable.setColor(rectangleColor)
    background = backgroundDrawable
```

Animate Color Change

```
  val objectAnimator = ObjectAnimator.ofObject(backgroundDrawable, "color",
        ArgbEvaluator(),
        Color.parseColor("#FFFFFFFF"), 
        Color.parseColor("#FF78c5f9"))

  objectAnimator .setDuration(1000);
  objectAnimator .start();
```

[image]