# Wrong 1st argument type

Tags: java, android, animation, this, android-context

I am relatively new to Java and Android development, so I am sorry for disturbing you.
I want to create fade-in animation on long click using AnimationUtils.LoadAnimation(), but I am facing error:

> Wrong 1st argument type. Found: 'android.view.View.OnLongClickListener', required: 'android.content.Context'

This is my code:

```
  BasicsButton.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onLongClick(View v) {

            Vibrator vib = (Vibrator) getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE);
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
                vib.vibrate(VibrationEffect.createOneShot(500,VibrationEffect.DEFAULT_AMPLITUDE));
            }else{
                vib.vibrate(500);
            }
                Animation in = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.fadein);
                blurView.startAnimation(in);
                blurView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            return true;
        }
```

I am unaware of what is wrong, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11419141/fading-in-text-in-android-using-animationutils-loadanimation) example seems to work, but not for me.

Thank you in advance. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**The problem is following line**

`Animation in = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.fadein);`

Since the above method is call in anonymous class, `this` refers to `OnLongClickListener` rather than Activity.

**Change it to as follows:**

`Animation in = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(<ActivityName>.this, R.anim.fadein);`

Comment: @KrumCvetkov great! remember to mark answer as accepted if it was useful, so that others can benefit too.

Comment: Sure I will, I just have to wait few mins because Stack Overflow does not let me to mark it yet. :)

Comment: @KrumCvetkov sure. Enjoy coding

Answer (score 3):

if you use this code inside a fragment, use **getContext()** instead of this.

Have you tried the below code:

```
  Vibrator vib = (Vibrator) getContext().getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE);
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
               vib.vibrate(VibrationEffect.createOneShot(500,VibrationEffect.DEFAULT_AMPLITUDE));
            }else{
                vib.vibrate(500);
            }
            Animation in = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getContext(), R.anim.slide_in_left);
            blurView.startAnimation(in);
            blurView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
```